# cPickle.load() doesnt accept non-.gz files, what can I use for .pkl files?

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, theano, lstm

I am trying to run an example of a LSTM recurrent neural network that is presented in this git: https://github.com/mesnilgr/is13.

I've installed theano and everything and when I got to the point of running the code, I've noticed the data was not being downloaded, so I've opened an issue on the github (https://github.com/mesnilgr/is13/issues/12) and this guy came up with a solution that consisted in:

1-get the data from the dropbox link he provides.
2- change the code of the 'load.py' file to download, and read the data properly.

The only issue is that the data in the dropbox folder(https://www.dropbox.com/s/3lxl9jsbw0j7h8a/atis.pkl?dl=0) is not a compacted .gz file as, I suppose, was the data from the original repository. So I dont have enough skill to change the code in order to do with the uncompressed data exaclty what it would do with the compressed one. Can someone help me?

The modification suggested and the changes I've done are described on the issue I've opened on the git(https://github.com/mesnilgr/is13/issues/12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is using

```
gzip.open(...)
```

But if the file is not gzipped then you probably just need to remove the `gzip.` prefix and use

```
open(...)
```

Comment: Are you sure you changed it in every place `gzip.open` is used? Try removing the `import gzip` line. The "IOError: Not a gzipped file" error message shouldn't appear if the `gzip` package is not being used at all.

Comment: removed another call of gzip on another file and that's it. Thanks!